# Validation for three unique fields and soft deletes

Tags: mysql, laravel, validation, request, unique

Last year I made a **laravel** site with an **events** table where I needed three fields to be unique for any event (place, date and time). I wasn't able to set up a validation request to do this so I added an unique index for these three fields directly through **phpmyadmin** and catching the exception that could happen if a duplicated event was inserted.

So basically my **store()** method has a `try/catch` like this:

```
try {

    $event = new Event;
    $event->place = $request->input('place');
    $event->date = $request->input('date');
    $event->time = $request->input('time');
    $event->save();

    return view(...);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    // Exception if place-date-time is duplicated
    if($e->getCode() === '23000') {
        return view('event.create')
                ->withErrors("Selected date and time is not available");
    }
}
```

Well, now I had to change the app so events could be soft deleted and I simply added the 'deleted_at' field to the unique index, thinking it would be so easy... This approach doesn't work anymore so I've been reading here and there about this problem and the only thing I get is I should do it through a validation request with unique, but honestly I just don't get the syntax for this validation rule with three fields that can't be equal while a fourth one, deleted_at, being null.

My app checks for the available places, dates and times and doesn't let the user choose any not available event but no matter how many times I've told them there's always someone who uses the browser back button and saves the event again :(

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good approach to solve the problem.
You can do follow things to solve this problem

- Before insert into database get a specific row if exist from database
  and store into a variable.
- Then check the data is already stored into the database or not.
- If data is already there create custom validation message using Message Bag Like below.

```
$ifExist = $event
            ->wherePlace(request->input('place'))
            ->whereDate(request->input('date'))
            ->whereTime(request->input('time'))
            ->exist();

if ($ifExist) return 'already exist';
```

It might help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have done eventually, but I would still prefer the validation unique rule solution, do you have any clue about its syntax in this case?

Comment: @Alvaro you should also make a `UNIQUE` multicolumn key on the columns place, date and time in your table also otherwise this piece off code can be prone to **race conditions**, without a `UNIQUE` key in the table this code is also **not** a good approach  to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

@narayanshama91 have pointed the right way.

You said you would like to use the `unique` rule to validate the input but the problem is that last week there was a post in [Laravel Blog](https://blog.laravel.com/unique-rule-sql-injection-warning) warning users of a possible `SQL Injection` via the unique rule if the input is provided by the user.

I would highly advise you to **NOT USE** this rule in this case since you depend on users input.

The correct approach in your case would be @narayanshama91 answer.

```
$ifExist = $event
    ->wherePlace(request->input('place'))
    ->whereDate(request->input('date'))
    ->whereTime(request->input('time'))
    ->exist();
    if ($ifExist) {
       return 'already exist';
    }
```

Comment: Also this code is prone to race conditions without a multicolumn unique key on the columns place, date and time..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Agreed. I'm not sure if a race condition would happen in his case (depending on application load) but you are right

Comment: Murphy's law *"Anything that can go wrong, will"*? Always keep it in mind.. *"I'm not sure if a race condition would happen in his case (depending on application load)"* Also a increase in users will increase the chance that it can happen offcource

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @Charlie. I thought the validation rule was a more elegant solution but this changes everything.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, thing is if I set a unique key with place, date and time and there is a soft deleted record with a given trio of values, I can't store a new one with the same values as it collides with the deleted one. Adding deleted_at column to the unique key doesn't work as It seems the unique key allows NULL values.